# Setting backgroundImage of a View using toImage() method on another view

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have been trying to set the backgroundImage of a view by using the toImage() method on another view.

This is working fine in iPhone, but not on iPad or Android.

```
$.VIEW_1.toImage( function (blob) {
    $.VIEW_2.backgroundImage = blob; // working fine on iPhone only and not on iPad or Android.

});
```

Please hint me how to set the backgroundImage a blob object as we can set for ImageView.

Thanks

Comment: If this works on iPhone but not on iPad it could very well be a memory issue. Is there anything in the logs confirming that?

Comment: No, it doesn't showing any logs and neither it is throwing any red-screen Application error, the code is just executing as it is, but no background Image is shown that way. From the docs, backgroundImage takes "String", so according to the docs, it is correct for devices other than iPhone, but then why it is working only on iPhone?

Is there any way that I can know more about this issue?

Comment: What does that red-screen application error say?

Comment: There is no red-screen application error, as I already said that the code keeps executing as if there were no error, but only iPhone shows backgroundImage.

I am setting backgroundImage this way to set a blur effect (using bencoding blur module) on modal window on iOS so that it looks like modal window is transparent with blur effect because we cannot set transparent background on modal window.

I use toImage() on NavigationWindow id (to include nav bar also) to truly create a transparent effect and then use this blob to set the backgroundImage of modal window.

Comment: O sorry, misread your previous comment thinking it did. I think this is a memory issue then. I'd suggest opening a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org) with a reproducible test case.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)

I will create a JIRA ticket after writing a proper test-code to reproduce it.

Comment: @Fokke, I tried a demo code to produce it and it was working fine.

But the real problem is with this [Adriano's Blur Module](https://github.com/adrianopaladini/Live-blurView).

Sorry, I did not remember the correct name of module while posting my second last comment.